# Fetch response of a GET request in a serializable object

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am trying to store the response of my GET request in one of the Bean classes I have built but I see the values being fetched as null in the variables declared inside the POJO.

Below is the code of GET request.

```
 ValidatableResponse response = given().header("Authorization", token).header("Content-type", "application/json")
                    .when().log().all().pathParam("CalendarId", testCaseBean.getCalendarId().toString()).urlEncodingEnabled(false)
                    .queryParam("from", testCaseBean.getStartDate()).queryParam("to", testCaseBean.getEndDate())
                    .queryParam("monthEnd", testCaseBean.getMonthEndBusinessDay())
                    .get(EndPoint.GET_CALENDAR_DETAILS_BY_MULTIPLE_CALENDAR_CODE).then().log().all();
    
            IndexCalendarDateResponseBeanactualRIOutput = CommonUtils.getJSONMapper()
                    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                    .readValue(response.extract().asString(), IndexCalendarDateResponseBean.class)

;
```

Below is the IndexCalendarDateResponseBean bean class

```
package com.tar.indexes.bean;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import com.tar.indexes.marketdata.api.dto.IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class IndexCalendarDateResponseBean {
    
    List<IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper> calendarId;

}
```

The IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper and the API response is as follows.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class InCalendarDateResponseWrapper {

    private String calendarId;

    private LocalDate calDat;

    private LocalDate prevBus;

    private LocalDate nextBus;

    private Boolean bus;

    private Boolean  monthEnd;

}
```

The response of the GET API is as follows.

```
{
    "EU": [
        {
            "calendarId": "EU",
            "calDat": "2022-11-01",
            "prevBus": "2022-10-31",
            "nextBus": "2022-11-02",
            "bus": true,
            "monthEnd": false
        }
    ],
    "AU": [
        {
            "calendarId": "AU",
            "calDat": "2022-11-01",
            "prevBus": "2022-10-31",
            "nextBus": "2022-11-02",
            "bus": true,
            "monthEnd": false
        }
    ]
}
```

When I am trying to debug and print one of the values inside the response using,

```
String t = actualRIOutput.getCalendarId().get(0).getCalendarId();
        System.out.println(t);
```

I am getting t value as null instead of EU. Any mistake I am doing fetching the values of the response?

Comment: What is `CommonUtils`?

Comment: Do you generate the JSON response yourself or are you dependent of an API?

Comment: Dependent on API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using a custom deserializer. But I had to create a specific enum  `Country` representing the 'countries' (not really countries, but I didn't found a better name ;-) ).
This solution assumes that service/API will return 0 or 1 entry for each 'country code'.

See the code below:

**enum Country**

```
public enum Country {
    EU("EU"), AU("AU") [,... other countries as needed];

    String code;

    Country(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    String code() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

**Class IndexCalendarDateResponseBean**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class IndexCalendarDateResponseBean {

    private List<IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper> calendarId;

    public IndexCalendarDateResponseBean() {
        super();
        calendarId = new ArrayList<IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper>();
    }

    public List<IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper> getCalendarId() {
        return calendarId;
    }

    public void setCalendarId(List<IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper> calendarId) {
        this.calendarId = calendarId;
    }
}
```

**Class IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper {

    private String calendarId;

    private LocalDate calDat;

    private LocalDate prevBus;

    private LocalDate nextBus;

    private Boolean bus;

    private Boolean monthEnd;

    public String getCalendarId() {
        return calendarId;
    }

    public LocalDate getCalDat() {
        return calDat;
    }

    public void setCalDat(LocalDate calDat) {
        this.calDat = calDat;
    }

    public LocalDate getPrevBus() {
        return prevBus;
    }

    public void setPrevBus(LocalDate prevBus) {
        this.prevBus = prevBus;
    }

    public LocalDate getNextBus() {
        return nextBus;
    }

    public void setNextBus(LocalDate nextBus) {
        this.nextBus = nextBus;
    }

    public Boolean getBus() {
        return bus;
    }

    public void setBus(Boolean bus) {
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public Boolean getMonthEnd() {
        return monthEnd;
    }

    public void setMonthEnd(Boolean monthEnd) {
        this.monthEnd = monthEnd;
    }

    public void setCalendarId(String calendarId) {
        this.calendarId = calendarId;
    }
    
    private void appendText(StringBuilder sb, String text) {
        sb.append(text).append("\n");
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        appendText(sb, "\tbus: "+getBus());
        appendText(sb, "\tcalDat: "+getCalDat());
        appendText(sb, "\tcalendarId: "+getCalendarId());
        appendText(sb, "\tmonthEnd: "+getMonthEnd());
        appendText(sb, "\tnextBus: "+getNextBus());
        appendText(sb, "\tprevBus: "+getPrevBus());
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**CustomCountryDeserializer**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

public class CustomCountryDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<IndexCalendarDateResponseBean> {

    protected CustomCountryDeserializer(Class<IndexCalendarDateResponseBean> valueClass) {
        super(valueClass);
    }

    @Override
    public IndexCalendarDateResponseBean deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        IndexCalendarDateResponseBean bean = new IndexCalendarDateResponseBean();
        List<IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper> wrappers = new ArrayList<IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper>();
        IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper wrapper;

        Country c = null;
        JsonNode subNode;
        for (Country country : Country.values()) {
            subNode = node.get(country.code()).get(0);
            if (subNode.get("calendarId").asText().equals(country.code())) {
                c = country;
                wrapper = new IndexCalendarDateResponseWrapper();
                wrapper.setBus(subNode.get("bus").asBoolean());
                wrapper.setCalDat(LocalDate.parse(subNode.get("calDat").asText()));
                wrapper.setCalendarId(subNode.get("calendarId").asText());
                wrapper.setMonthEnd(subNode.get("monthEnd").asBoolean());
                wrapper.setNextBus(LocalDate.parse(subNode.get("nextBus").asText()));
                wrapper.setPrevBus(LocalDate.parse(subNode.get("prevBus").asText()));
                wrappers.add(wrapper);
            }
        }
        bean.setCalendarId(wrappers);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**A simple class to test all that stuff**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

public class TestRequestWithEnum {
    private String response;

    public TestRequestWithEnum() {
        super();
        this.initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the response string
     */
    private void initialize() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        appendLine(sb, "{");
        appendLine(sb, "\"EU\": [");
        appendLine(sb, "{");
        appendLine(sb, "\"calendarId\": \"EU\",");
        appendLine(sb, "\"calDat\": \"2022-11-01\",");
        appendLine(sb, " \"prevBus\": \"2022-10-31\",");
        appendLine(sb, " \"nextBus\": \"2022-11-02\",");
        appendLine(sb, "\"bus\": true,");
        appendLine(sb, "\"monthEnd\": false");
        appendLine(sb, " }");
        appendLine(sb, "],");
        appendLine(sb, "\"AU\": [");
        appendLine(sb, "{");
        appendLine(sb, "\"calendarId\": \"AU\",");
        appendLine(sb, "\"calDat\": \"2022-11-01\",");
        appendLine(sb, " \"prevBus\": \"2022-10-31\",");
        appendLine(sb, " \"nextBus\": \"2022-11-02\",");
        appendLine(sb, " \"bus\": true,");
        appendLine(sb, " \"monthEnd\": false");
        appendLine(sb, " }");
        appendLine(sb, "]");
        appendLine(sb, "}");

        this.response = sb.toString();
    }

    private void appendLine(StringBuilder sb, String text) {
        sb.append(text).append("\n");
    }

    public void testWithEnum() {
        ObjectMapper oMapper = new JsonMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        oMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);

        //Register a module with deserializer on ObjectMapper
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("CustomCountryDeserializer");
        module.addDeserializer(IndexCalendarDateResponseBean.class, new CustomCountryDeserializer(IndexCalendarDateResponseBean.class));
        oMapper.registerModule(module);
        try {
            //Deserialize string
            IndexCalendarDateResponseBean bean = oMapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<IndexCalendarDateResponseBean>() {});
            bean.getCalendarId() .forEach(calendarId -> System.out.println(calendarId.toString()));
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestRequestWithEnum test = new TestRequestWithEnum();
        test.testWithEnum();
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Console output]

Hope it helps...